# SwiftUI/Metal Text Render using CITextImageGenerator - change color

Tags: swiftui, metal, core-image, metalkit

I have written code to render text to a MTKView, but I have not found a way to modify the color of the text.  Has anyone had success with this or can someone more familiar with CoreImage assist?  Thank you.

```html
let image = CIFilter(name: "CITextImageGenerator", parameters: [
                "inputText": "Hello, World",
                            "inputFontName": "HelveticaNeue",
                            "inputFontSize": 12,
                            "inputScaleFactor": 2.0])?.outputImage!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an attributed string instead of string to a `CIAttributedTextImageGeneratorFilter` instance.

Comment: Thank you Moose, this works perfect!